# AIR iOS enterprise application fails to install from a remote location, but works fine locally

Tags: ios, air, codesign

I'm building an iPad app (Adobe AIR 28.0) for a corporate client, and I'm struggling to get it working when signing it using their enterprise certificate.

**What works:**

The IPA builds correctly and is successfully signed with their enterprise certificate and provisioning profile. The app is set to Ad Hoc, doesn't use a wildcard bundle ID (although their certs do: my app is com.companyname.thing, and their provisioning profiles/certs are com.companyname.*).

If I use iTunes to install the application while connected via USB, it works correctly. Additionally if I select to install to a connected device during compilation in Adobe Animate it also works fine.

Once installed, on the first run of the app it complains about not trusting the certificate (this is expected), and if I then go to Settings on the device and manually trust the cert, the application runs as expected. All fine and in line with what I'd expect with an enterprise application.

**What doesn't work:**

However: when uploading the same IPA to a remote location, the application will download but fails to install completely, giving me the "[appname] could not be installed" message. This occurs on my test devices, but also on the corporate devices which have the required certificate installed. This happens when I upload the build to HockeyApp, and also the client's corporate distribution system (I'm unsure what system this is, but the end result is the same when users download the app)

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be occurring?

EDIT:

I tried to pull the app down from a remote location while observing the XCode console, and found this error:

[image]

This is a start but isn't descriptive, what could be causing this? The profile is a valid Distribution one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd post the solution I found, in case any future folk encounter this. My issue was caused by **a script that was modifying the IPA and not re-signing it**.

The app went into a build system that strips out certain files for certain versions of the application, and then should re-sign it. The system was doing things in the wrong order - if you modifying the internals of a compiled IPA and then fail to re-sign it, it'll fail to install. This also explained why it worked locally. Whew.